# How to update the compose UI if the MutableLive<MutableList<Object>> value is coming from a third party SDK?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to implement a LazyVerticalGrid in compose using a list that I am retrieving from SDK. In SDK the getItems method returns a list of items in MutableLiveData<MutableList> format. I found that inside the SDK the Items data class is having objects declared as var. Currently I am unable to update the UI if there is a change in any of the value from items object?

Please provide a solution to the issue?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define it in your ViewModel like this, perhaps where you get a response and populate it.

```
var list = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Type>>()
```

and in your Composable function use it like this -

```
val list = viewModel.list.observeAsState().value
```